# flv to mp4 converter in Trusty

Tags: software-recommendation, video-conversion

Anybody recommend a GUI app (preferably in Ubuntu repos) to convert from .flv to .mp4 other than Transmageddon? Transmageddon now crashes in Trusty.

Comment: Take a look at [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).

Comment: I used VLC a lot to transcode. I think it uses some of the LI tools from the other answers as underlying engines. But it provides a GUI for the task.

Answer (score 13):

I don't think so there is GUI app is available in Ubuntu repository.

But you can simply convert your required formats in terminal. Try the following,

First you have to install `libav-tools`, Open terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type the below command,

```
$ sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

Now you can do your needs,  for FLV file to MP4

```
$ avconv -i input.flv -codec copy output.mp4
```

Comment: On 18.04 and above you can apt-get install `ffmpeg` and run the exact command substituting `ffmpeg` for `avconv`, so just do: `ffmpeg -i input.flv -codec copy output.mp4`

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [winff](http://winff.org/html_new/index.html)

It is a graphical application that uses `ffmpeg` (like a lot of other programs) to convert videos and audio.

It is included in the official Ubuntu repositories, so you can simply install it with

`sudo apt-get install winff`

The official website includes a link to a wiki and a mailing list if you need specific support and documentation with this tool

Answer (score 4):

[Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) is in the official repositories since **Trusty (14.04)**.
It is a small, efficient DVD ripper and video transcoder with a clean GTK GUI.

It can convert from a number of video formats, including **flv**, to either **MPEG-4** or **Matroska**.

To install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install handbrake
```

Comment: And Handbrake is of course available for Windows and OSX / macOS as well.

Answer (score 2):

Abstract from the blog **Transcoding an audio or a video file** - http://www.frasq.org/en/transcoding-an-audio-or-a-video-file (look for *mp4flv* in the page):

To convert a FLV already containing a video in H264 and an audio in AAC in MP4:

```
ffmpeg -i file.flv -acodec copy -vcodec copy -y video.mp4    

MP4Box -raw 1 video.mp4 -out video.h264
MP4Box -raw 2 video.mp4 -out audio.aac

MP4Box -add video.h264 -add audio.aac file.mp4

rm -f video.mp4 video.h264 audio.aac
```

If the FLV contains an audio in MP3, extract the video while converting the MP3 in AAC:

```
ffmpeg -i file.flv -vcodec copy -y video.h264 -f adts -ar 44100 -f wav -ac 2 - | faac -b 128 -o audio.aac -
```

Assemble the MP4 with MP4Box:

```
MP4Box -add video.h264 -add audio.aac file.mp4
```

The blog explains how to install *ffmpeg*, *faac*, *MP4Box*, etc.

La version en français : **Transcoder des fichiers audio et vidéo** - http://www.frasq.org/fr/transcoder-des-fichiers-audio-et-video

Answer (score 1):

```
avconv -i input.flv -c:a copy output.mp4
```

This has the effect of transcoding the video stream with the default codec and copying the audio stream.

avconv can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

Comment: @DavidFoerster This answer has different flags for avconv.  The flags in the top answer don't work for me, whereas these flags do

Comment: Fair enough. Could you please explain what this command will do, e. g. which streams are copied and which are transcoded (and to which codec)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the Ubuntu repository, but I liked *Format Junkie* for video conversions:

Add repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
```

Update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install formatjunkie
```

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

I've written a GUI (named ConvertFLVToMP4)for CLI avconv program. Its .deb can be downloaded from:
https://app.box.com/s/vyr473g7q2nwkj6haq22
It requires the installation of gambas3 from:
https://launchpad.net/~gambas-team/+archive/ubuntu/gambas3
before installing the app from the .deb.